# Accept incoming call in android 2.3.5

Tags: android

I am writing an application which override the default incoming call screen. So I have a button in my application for receiving calls. When user click on the button then the application will accept the call. So far I successful done on this application and can be using in android 2.3.4 or below without any problem. However, when I use the same application in android 2.3.5 , it cant accept the call. So I was wondering if there is another solution to accept call programmatically in android 2.3.5. Thanks in advance for any guidance provide. Below are the code for accept call.

```
    private static void answerPhoneHeadsethook(Context context) {
    // Simulate a press of the headset button to pick up the call
    Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);             
    buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

    // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);               
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
}
```

Comment: can you post what is working?

Comment: the code in my post is working in my 2.3.4 device but not working in my 2.3.5 device. The 2.3.4 device is sony ericsson active while the 2.3.5 device is star A3.

Comment: both look the same except for ACTION_UP and DOWN?

Comment: yes, for froyo and beyond, the call will be accepted when the headset button is being press down and then release(so is down up) while anything before froyo, the call will be accepted if when the headset button is press down. Above code can be use for froyo and until 2.3.4 . But it cant be used for 2.3.5 as the call did not accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Check this guy's update...I think this is what you need!
http://androidbridge.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/ source code:

```
AutoAnswer is a very simple android application to answer the phone automatically when it rings. Can be limited to just contacts or starred contacts. Also has a speakerphone option.
```

http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/

Comment: I had looked that source code before and I am using the same code like the code in that project for accepting call. It worked in my android 2.3.4 device. However, the same code is not working in my android 2.3.5 device. By the way, both device are using the same application.

Comment: I am trying the same thing. However, it is not working on my device but working on the emulater both are 2.3.3....Any idea? Is this connected to your problem?

Comment: So far the solution is working in my device(2.3.4), but I did not try on emulator.